# Comparing inner loop variable with outer loop variable- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a code for a multiplication table and I was advised the following: 
"You could compare the inner loop variable with the outer loop value... e.g., i > a"
What is meant by this? Is there something that I'm not doing correct?

Thanks in Advance!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Java Script </title>
  <h1> 6.2 Task JavaScript </h1>
  <script>
    var times = 1;
    for (a = 9; a > 0; a--) {
      for (i = 9; i > 0 && i > (9 - times); i--) {
        document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + ' ');
      }
      document.write('<br>');
      times++;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't explained what you are attempting. So ""You could compare the inner loop variable with the outer loop value" has no context.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, both `a` and `i` should be declared with `let` or `var`.

Comment: I believe `i > 9-times` can be replaced with `i > a`. Also, add `let` or `var` in your loop statement

Comment: If you replace your inner loop condition with `i>=a` you'll get the same result, but the condition is simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can shorten the code a little if you compare the inner varibale a against i instead of using a second variable times:

```js
for (a = 9; a > 0; a--) {
    for (i = 9; i > 0 && i > a - 1; i--) {
        document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + ' ');
    }
    document.write('<br>');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `times` is not needed, and instead of using `9 - times` you can use `a - 1` because that always gives the same value.

**Demo:**

```js
for (a = 9; a > 0; a--) {
  for (i = 9; i > 0 && i > a - 1; i--) {
    document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + ' ');
  }
  document.write('<br>');
}
```

Alternatively you can use `i >= a` instead of `i > a - 1` and the condition for `i > 0` is superfluous:

```js
for (a = 9; a > 0; a--) {
  for (i = 9; i >= a; i--) {
    document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + ' ');
  }
  document.write('<br>');
}
```